# How do I show a percentage value in a views_field?

Tags: 7, views, entities

How do I show the percentage value in a views_field?

- col(1) (group by) field_a
- col(2) (count)field_a *100/number of results " -->@total"

I'm still not able to use @total in a computed_field or a math-expression_field or a global_custom_field.

I need this value for the [Highcharts](https://www.drupal.org/project/highcharts) module, so using "aggregation plus" also seems not the solution.

Using a PHP field inside views is highly risky for security reasons as I read here in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve some calculations I see 2 different solutions.

1/ You create a custom sql query with (db_query) inside a custom module that gonna trigger a view to render, your select clause will make the calculation for you so you will have your result that you are going to display inside a custom field in your view.
You can see the actual query you are executing by using the [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and then tweak it.

2/ You can use [computed_field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) but it's a really dangerous thing to integrate PHP inside a field somewhere, because if your php breaks, you will break your complete site, and need to rollback your database. But I don't suggest this solution because it's really risky for your site.

I hope it helps

Cheers

Comment: ty denis, additional info: the view i'm talking about, is part of a series from global view areas (all highcharts) with inherit contextual date filters. Do you still think, i can reach this with your suggestion 1/? The value i need is yet there, but on the wrong place as i can display it in "global:result summary @total". So suggestion /1 is a redundant query, isn't it? My idea is to bring this existing @total to sthg like a custom token - have you an additional idea? sry for my english

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure to understand well, but if the value is already in the view, try to display all the fields you have access to,but you won't be able to do a calculation on it. Then add a custom field at the end of your list of fields, and by using "rewrite the output" you might find what you want about replacement tokens.

Comment: what i mean is: by adding a global:result summery for example in the views header  - there is a token called "@ total" showing total numbers of rows in the view. But in dont get access to this token, in the replacement patterns or "rewrite the output- replacements" of any field. With this @total i would be able to do all the following stuff i need. Hope this was understandable ;)

Comment: Having some information in the view header doesn't mean having information in the resultset.